# Redirect after login in site

Tags: c#, asp.net, web-applications, redirect, authentication

i use asp login control in web application (ASP.NET 4). if user in **admin** role i want redirect to admin page.

i use this code, but not working:

```
protected void baseLogin1_LoggingIn(object sender, LoginCancelEventArgs e)
    {
        if (Page.User.Identity.IsAuthenticated && Roles.IsUserInRole(Page.User.Identity.Name, "Admin"))
        {
            Page.Response.Redirect("admin/Default.aspx");
        }
    }
```

please help me.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

LoggingInEvent is raised before the user is authenticated. So the first part of your condition is always false. Move you logics under LoggedIn event. 
Try this one:

```
protected void baseLogin1_LoggedIn(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    if (Context.User.Identity.IsAuthenticated && Context.User.IsInRole("Admin"))
    {
        Context.Response.Redirect("admin/Default.aspx");
    }
}
```

Comment: Page.User.Identity.IsAuthenticated And Roles.IsUserInRole(Page.User.Identity.Name, "Admin") not working.

Comment: The LoggingIn event is raised when a user submits login information but before the user is authenticated on the Web site. Use the LoggingIn event to set up any information that you need before authenticating a user.
You can cancel a login attempt during the LoggingIn event by setting the Cancel property of the CancelEventArgs object to true.
After the LoggingIn event is raised, the Login control raises the Authenticate event and then the LoggedIn event.

Answer (score 1):

Use the LoggedIn event: Event description is [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ui.webcontrols.login.loggedin%28v=vs.100%29.aspx)

You should really be using `Server.Transfer("~/admin/Default.aspx");` as it is a little more efficient (less round trips).

If the page needs to preserve the query string for a bookmark or it is important to preseve the correct URL in the browser then `Response.Redirect()` is needed but be aware of the extra bandwidth cost.